# Why does oil not stop on a crease

Tags: homework-and-exercises, experimental-physics, everyday-life, home-experiment

I did an experiment in class where we had to roll different liquids down a ramp for viscosity. the ramp was a CD case covered in tin foil. Two of the liquids we used were water and oil. When the water came to a crease in the tin foil it paused but the oil didn't. Why is this?

Comment: This is almost certainly a question of surface tension. Could you please post a sketch / diagram / photo of the experimental setup?

Comment: sorry, my computer is really old and won't allow me to post pictures. There was just a CD case covered in tin foil set up at a 52º angle. The fluids were placed at the top, then we recorded the time that it took for them to roll 18 cm and any other observations that we had.